# How can I change the content "color" of a button in wpf

Tags: wpf, button, colors

```
<StackPanel Margin="2">
  <Button Name="btn" Click="btn_Click" Content="Load Profile Image">
    <Button.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="D:\Pictures\rectangles.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </Button.Background>
  </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Image that i am pasting here is of is almost black, so I want to change the content color to white so that it should appear properly.

My apology, I hadn't added color in title which is quoted in commas, sorry for my mistake. Now it is OK, I think now it is clear to the reader ;)

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking here. Your ImageBrush takes the ImageSource (without altering it) and displays it as the background of your button. If you want the image to be "brighter", then you need to change the brightness of your image.

Comment: Could you show us this 'rectangles.jpg' image?

Comment: Thank you Mike Eason and Lujasz Rejman.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the color of the Text you are displaying you want the `Foreground` property.

```
<Button Name="btn" Click="btn_Click" Content="Load Profile Image" Foreground="White">
```

Comment: yes, this is the answer of my question. Thank you Steve :)

Comment: For multiple colors, define the content in a nested `TextBlock` containing `Run` blocks for each color. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29756258/2939139

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to change the background and foreground of a button then do this

```
<Button Name="btn" Content="Load Profile Image">
   <Button.Background>
      <ImageBrush ImageSource="D:\Pictures\rectangles.jpg"></ImageBrush>
   </Button.Background>
   <Button.Foreground>
   <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" >
       <GradientStop Color="YellowGreen" Offset="0.25" />
       <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="1.5" />
   </LinearGradientBrush>
   </Button.Foreground>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we understand what you want here coz when you provide an image as background it will become background.

if you want Image , text and background to a button try this

```
 <Button Name="btn" Background="Red">
            <Button.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="D:\Pictures\rectangles.jpg"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Text="Load Profile Image" ></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```