# How can I set the Content of a WPF Button to have multiple colors?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, colors, wpf-controls

I would like the `Content` of my WPF `Button` to use multiple colors like, e.g.:

```
<Button Name="MyButton">
    <Blue>This is</Blue>
    <Red>Red</Red>
</Button>
```

I see that I can't use multiple `Run`s like in a `TextBlock` - what is the proper method for achieving this effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `TextBlock` as `Button.Content`

```
<Button Name="MyButton">
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Foreground="Blue" Text="This is Blue"/>
        <Run Foreground="Red" Text=" This is Red"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

`Button` is [`ContentControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) and as such

> The ContentControl can contain any type of common language runtime object (such as a string or a DateTime object) or a UIElement object (such as a Rectangle or a Panel)